# Azure DevOps Build validation - use existing CI run

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a small project set up in Azure DevOps with a feature / master workflow, in which the master is protected in two ways:

- Merges happen only via Pull Requests
- Pull Requests must have a green
  CI build:

[image]

Unfortunately, this contradicts with the CI: My CI build is defined to run on every commit on the remote (which is the best practice to get fast feedback, as far as I know).
The problem is, that Azure DevOps doesn't recognize the "Commit Trigger" CI Build and either starts another one or the developer needs to start the CI manually to fulfill the build policy.
[image]

From what I remember from tools like Bamboo, this should be one workflow: A policy takes the last run without needing a specific source like Commit trigger of PR trigger.
Did Microsoft change the concept here deliberately, or is there a workaround to have both triggers (PR and commit) in place without needing two runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a build policy in the PR, that build must to run when you create the PR regardless of whether this build is triggered either by the CI.

The reason is simple, the CI build run on the branch source code (for example `feature` branch), this is not enough in the PR because even the CI build is passes, he passed on the `feature` branch, you can't know if it will pass in the `master` branch.

So, when a PR is created, ADO is trigger a new build that run on the `master` branch with the changes of the `feature` branch, and when this build is passed you can know for sure that the merge will not break `master` code.

How ADO can check the `master` with the `feature` changes before the merge? behind the scenes, the build do a merge locally, and on this merge run the build.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. So is this concept just fundamentally different from he likes of GitHub? Are the other tools running pr policies just against the branch without the pre-merge to master then?

Comment: I don't think so, there is no point to run the policy without pre-merge.

Comment: Ok thank you, do you know by chance, what the best practice here is? CI and PR?

Comment: https://holgerfrohloff.de/best-practices-on-doing-pull-requests

Comment: thanks. Is this standard process to run PR check/build? Or is specific to ADO?

Comment: @toto' this is a standard process :)